# Why is does this error happen? "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

When I try to click the Button1 ,2 and 3. The error that is stated below happens. This error always occur when I have two tables on my database.

> No value given for one or more required parameters

This is my code

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Module MSAccessConnection
    Public Function OpenConnection() As String
        Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=G:\MerdoresNew\OrderData.accdb"

        Return connString
    End Function
End Module


Public Class Order
    Public total As Integer
    Public ordered As Integer
    Public ordered2 As Integer

    Public ordered3 As Integer
    Public price As Integer
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection


    Private Sub Order_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'OrderDatabaseDataSet.Items' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        myConnection.ConnectionString = OpenConnection()
        myConnection.Open()

        'the query:
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Price] FROM [Items] where Item='Cheese Burger'", myConnection)

        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        ' the following variable is hold true if user is found, and false if user is not found
        Dim Found As Boolean = False

        While dr.Read
            Found = True
            price = dr("Price")
        End While

        If Found = True Then


            ordered = TextBox1.Text * price



        Else





            MsgBox("Saved!")

            Me.Close()


        End If

        myConnection.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        myConnection.ConnectionString = OpenConnection()
        myConnection.Open()

        'the query:
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Price] FROM [Items] where Item='Ham Burger'", myConnection)

        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        ' the following variable is hold true if user is found, and false if user is not found
        Dim Found As Boolean = False

        While dr.Read
            Found = True
            price = dr("Price")
        End While

        If Found = True Then


            ordered2 = TextBox2.Text * price




        Else








            MsgBox("Saved!")


        End If

        myConnection.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        total = ordered + ordered2 + ordered3
        Form1.TextBox1.Text = total





    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        myConnection.ConnectionString = OpenConnection()
        myConnection.Open()

        'the query:
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Price] FROM [Items] where Item='Chicken Sandwich'", myConnection)

        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        ' the following variable is hold true if user is found, and false if user is not found
        Dim Found As Boolean = False

        While dr.Read
            Found = True
            price = dr("Price")
        End While

        If Found = True Then


            ordered3 = TextBox3.Text * price




        Else


            MsgBox("Saved!")

        End If

        myConnection.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Could you take the time to format your code correctly? And provide succinct code to accompany your question? I see several routines all communicating with a database. Surely one routine is enough to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This is currently a debugging question but you've given us not much to go on apart from a load of code.

Comment: Check that the column and table names in the code are the same in the database. Also, if you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) then Visual Studio will point out some problems for you and even suggest some fixes.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see where you are passing your connection string to the button click handler. You DIM the connection string as connString, but you never call it in the handler.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    myConnection.ConnectionString = OpenConnection() <----- Change ConnectionString to connString
    myConnection.Open()
```

I think that's the variable that you're missing. I would have commented but I don't have enough rep to comment yet.

Comment: The OP is using the function `OpenConnection()` to get the connection string. `connString` is not in scope where you suggest using it, although `connString` is not a property of an OleDbConnection anyway.

Comment: I missed the OleDbConnection part and just saw the SQL tag. My bad.